# Can't apply Union in List<anonymous> LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am trying to union two results of LINQ query with my `DbContext`:

```
var innerJoin = (from pg in context.TbPlageAccueil
                             join pf in context.TbPermanence on pg.IdPlageAccueil equals pf.IdPlage
                             where pf.HeureDebPerm > new DateTime(2016, 10, 1) && pf.HeureFinPerm < new DateTime(2016, 12, 31)
                             select new{ Libelle_Activite = pg.LibellePlageAccueil, Heure_Debut_Activite = pf.HeureDebPerm, Heure_Fin_Activit = pf.HeureFinPerm }).ToList();

var reunion= (from ru in context.TbReunion select new { Libelle_Activite = ru.IntituleReunion, Heure_Debut_Activite = ru.HeureDebRn, Heure_Fin_Activite = ru.HeureFinRn }).ToList();
```

When I apply union for those two results I get this error :

> CS1929 C# 'List << anonymous type: string Libelle_Activite, DateTime?
>   Activity_Start_Time, DateTime? Time_Fin_Activit >> Queryable.Union <<
>   anonymous type: string Libelle_Activite, DateTime?
>   Activity_Start_Time, DateTime? Time_Fin_Activite >> (IQueryable <<
>   anonymous type: string Activity_Label, DateTime? Activity_Start_Time,
>   DateTime? Time_Time_Time >>, IEnumerable << type anonymous: string
>   Activity_Label, DateTime? Time_Time_Time >>, IEnumerable << type
>   anonymous: string Activity_Label, DateTime? Time_Time_Activity >>,
>   DateEnime? << anonymous type: string Libelle_Activite, DateTime?
>   Time_Debut_Activite, DateTime? Time_End_Activite

What I am doing wrong ?
How to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have defined a property `Heure_Fin_Activit` In the `innerJoin`, while it is `Heure_Fin_Activite` in the `reunion`. You need to make sure they have the same names and types:

```
var reunion= (from ru in context.TbReunion select new 
              { Libelle_Activite = ru.IntituleReunion, 
                Heure_Debut_Activite = ru.HeureDebRn, 
                Heure_Fin_Activit = ru.HeureFinRn }).ToList();
```

Comment: hh that made  stressed me 1 hour :) , i need to change my glasses :D